# Getting undefined for keys when trying to extract/retrieve all the values from Firebase DB using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I have the following piece of code that retrieves records from `Firebase` DB using `Angular` and `Ionic`.

It works fine but does not give me the keys for each records. It gives me '`undefined`'

I looked into various online tutorials and it looks like switching from `valueChanges()` to `snapshotChanges()` will do the job, but each online tutorial shows a different way to extract records there are also version discrepancies between what I am using and the one's that are online.

Since I am coming from Java world I am quite new to JS world.

Please guide.

**home.ts**

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

    private items$: Item[] = [];

    constructor(private  shoppingListService: ShoppingListService) {
      this.shoppingListService.getShoppingList().valueChanges().subscribe((datas) => {
        datas.forEach(data => {
          console.log(data);

          //data.key is undefined here
          console.log("=>" + data.key + " " + data.name + " " + data.quantity + " " + data.price);
          this.items$.push({key: data.key, name: data.name, quantity: data.quantity, price: data.price});
        })
      }, (err) => {
        console.log("problem:", err);
      });
    }

}
```

**ShoppingListService.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ShoppingListService {

  //here 'shopping-list' is the name of the table
  private shoppingListRef = this.db.list<Item>('shopping-list');

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.getShoppingList();
  }

  getShoppingList() {
    return this.shoppingListRef;
  }

}
```

**Item.model.ts**

```
export interface Item {
  key?: string;
  name: string;
  quantity: number;
  price: number
}
```

**package.json**

```
"angularfire2": "^5.1.0",
"firebase": "^5.5.9",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "^6.0.0",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
```

**ionic info**

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.4.0 (C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

System:

   NodeJS : v10.13.0 (C:\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```

[image]

Comment: if u want the metadata then use snapshotChanges() . see https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#snapshotchanges

Comment: @MuruGan - Thanks for the answer. So how would I iterate over the values and build and array out of it? That's where majority of the confusion is for me. I have googled around for answers but all of them show different ways of doing it based on whatever version of dependency they imported. Any pointers ???

Answer (score 0):

```
this.shoppingListService.getShoppingList().snapshotChanges().pipe(map((actions) => {
   actions.map(action => {
      console.log(action.payload.doc.data());
      var data = action.payload.doc.data();
      var id = action.payload.doc.id;
     //data.key is undefined here
      console.log("=>" + id + " " + data.name + " " + data.quantity + " " + data.price);
      this.items$.push({key: id, name: data.name, quantity: data.quantity, price: data.price});
    })
  }), catchError((err) => {
    console.log("problem:", err);
  });
```

try it and lemme know if u have any issues. Please import pipe, map and catchError from rxjs like below

```
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

**Angular Version is 6**

Follow this link [How to use snapshotchanges](https://alligator.io/angular/cloud-firestore-angularfire/#updating-and-deleting-items)

Comment: As soon as I copy-paste the above code it complains at the very first line. Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot<Item>>[]>'.

Comment: Special thanks to you for the extra effort you are putting in but even after copy-pasting the above changes it was complaining about the import statements that you mentioned above. To me it looks like a `RxJS` version mismatch issue. The editor is complaining about the `doc` and `.data()` also. However, when I change it to `.val()` the editor does not show any red marks and everything gets compiled but still no data shows up in the UI. When I look at the console logs it does not anything in `action.payload.val()`. So it looks like it is not even going inside the `actions.map` callback method.